# Could not find package laravel/laravel with stability stable when using isolated repository

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, nexus, sonatype

Using Sonatype Nexus, the repository is configured to install packages via packagist.org. But still when I try to install a clean Laravel project for example:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

And I get the following error:

> Could not find package laravel/laravel with stability stable

Does it mean that the Nexus is not configured properly? Or I am doing something wrong and need to configure something in my `composer.json` before when using such repository?